# username and password not found-php

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

**I am trying to login in my site but at the time of login its showing that username and password not found in my login page. 
Please somebody help me**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function register() {
        window.location = '<?= indexurl() ?>home/register';
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

<div data-role="page" id="login" data-theme="b">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h3>Login to Account</h3>
    </div>
    <?php if ($this->ShowError == true) {?>
    <div>
        User name or password not found
    </div> 
    <?php } ?>
        <form method="post" action="<?= indexurl() . "home/do_login" ?>">
           <fieldset>
                 <div data-role="fieldcontain">                                      
                    <label for="username">Email:</label>
                    <input type="text" value="" name="password" id="username"/> 
                </div>                             
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">                                      
                    <label for="password">Enter your password:</label>
                    <input type="password" value="" name="password" id="password"/> 
                </div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="login" value="Login">
                <input type="button" value="Register" onclick="register()">
            </fieldset>
        </form>                              

    </div>
```

Comment: Where is your php login script?

Comment: No. That is not very smart to give out your information.

Comment: I meant post it in your question.

Comment: Ok, well post your login script and people will try to help.

Comment: We are not support. We just help with the code.

Comment: i just made changes with this code..i didn't touch anything else.

Comment: i integrate bootstrap code in it and just after that it is showing error

Comment: Did you change any of the names or id's?

Comment: yes..but now i dont know what was that code?

Comment: You will have to undo it somehow. Ask the person who made the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="password" id="username"/>
```

Should be changed to:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="username" id="username"/>
```

So that you don't have two inputs with the name *password*

Answer (score 0):

both input elements have "password" names in attributes. (The ids are different, but names are same). Change:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="password" id="username">
```

to

```
<input type="text" value="" name="username" id="username">
```